# (Closed) dont reset control Text / value when navigate to other UserControl in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, user-controls

Im using Panel as container of UserControls that can navigate using Menustrip.

The Problem is when im trying to switch to other page/usercontrol and back to that usercontrol. All controls value / text reset to initial state.

Example :

1. initial state of label Text in UserControl1 is "Rp. 0" then changed to "Rp. 10.000"
2. Navigate to other UserControl and back.
3. the label text reset to initial state "Rp. 0" (how to prevent this from happening)

By the way, im using Controls.Clear Method in switching user controls

```csharp
panelHalamanUtama.Controls.Clear();
panelHalamanUtama.Controls.Add(uc);
uc.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Comment: How are you loading your user control again? Are you re-initializing it ?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @AmitVerma

Yes i've figured it out about that. im using `new` keyword to load them in toolstrip menu item event. So i change it by moving the `new` instance inside the class of the form so i just call the instanced of them in event method.